# Finding previous tag name using jQuery Prev()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey all I am using the following code to go back 1 in order to find the start of the tag name:

```
console.log($('text[text-anchor=\'middle\']').prev().prop("tagName"));
```

This produces this result:

> text

However, that is incorrect since it should be **< g>**
[image]

If I do this:

```
console.log($('text[text-anchor=\'middle\']').prev())
```

I get this:

[image]

So I know its getting the correct area but how can I go about getting the **< g>**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g` tag is parent of text elements. You need to use `.parent()` or `.closest()` selector for traversing to parent element:

```
$('text[text-anchor=\'middle\']').parent()
```

or

```
$('text[text-anchor=\'middle\']').closest('g')
```

Comment: Nice one, Milind. That did it! Thanks!

Comment: @StealthRT: glad it helps :)